# Binding component.ts with module.ts - Angular 2

Tags: windows, angular, typescript, angular2-template

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports:
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModeule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

I am recently learning Angular JS from it's official website. My site was working correctly at the starting but now I am stuck at binding the component to the module. I am getting error that it cannot find food. I don't have any idea what to do I have rechecked code several times .

[image]

Comment: you are naming your object by the name of the class `Food` , try to delete export in class Food and change the name of your object to ``food` for example

Comment: did that already..no use

Comment: Can you show the error message given in the console?